# Unrecognized database format message on local drive only

Tags: database, ms-access

I have the following very weird situation:

Access 2003 MDB application together with a SQL server backend
Application runs from local hard drive using Access Runtime viewer 2010 OR Access 2010
Windows 7 PC
On some PC's users get the infamous unrecognized database format message. It happens at some point while using the application, never at startup. After that the only solution is to stop and restart the application. Same effect, it works for a while and then fails.

Running exact the same version from a network drive does not give any issues. Replacing the Runtime Viewer with a full blown Access did not make any difference. On Windows XP we never had this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've tried the usual Repair/Compact by now?  Any strange outlier behavior like you're describing usually indicates some form of corruption.  At times, corruption goes deep and leaves behind artifacts that can never get resolved.  You may want to create a fresh, new DB and import all of the forms/reports/queries/etc... into the fresh DB.  This has fixed many issues similar to yours that I've encountered over the years.

Comment: Yes, rebuilding, compacting, compiling all tried. The most bizarre thing is that the exact same version runs fine from a network drive. That basically rules out corruption. Also, starting the same app from the local drive works fine (initially) without any corruption warnings. Even the 'time-of-crash' is not predictable, nor the specific functionality/form.

Comment: The app is about 100MB in size, has >100 forms, about 150 tables/SQL server views, >200 local queries and about 50 different reports.

Comment: Using the Sherlock Holmes Principal, what can you rule out?  So you're saying that User A runs this DB from their local drive, and it crashes.  Same User A runs this off the network drive and it never crashes?  And they're using Access, which is installed on their local drive, in both cases?